# Custom grant type in WSO2 IS 5.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I recently updated my environment from WSO2 IS 5.0.0 to WSO2 IS 5.2.0. My environment consists of 2 machines that are creating a cluster (using the WKA membership scheme and Load Balancer(AWS ELB) with sticky session enabled). I am using MySQL(not the default H2 database). The machines on which the IS is deployed are Windows Server 2012 R2 (EC2 AWS machines).
In the IS 5.0.0 version we had custom grant OAuth grant type. It was implemented following the article below:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Writing+a+Custom+OAuth+2.0+Grant+Type
After the upgrade process, the .jar file was added in the [IS_HOME]\repository\components\lib and the system was started successfully without errors in the console.log. But then when we started calling the token endpoint, the systems tarted to error out:
https://slack-files.com/T0DDMMC9Y-F2QRF2JLA-bcd85857dc
https://slack-files.com/T0DDMMC9Y-F2QRFES10-ab528f64e5
Then we rebuilt the custom OAuth grant type. We updated the org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth_4.2.3.jar to version 4.2.7. We followed these article:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Extension+Points+for+OAuth#ExtensionPointsforOAuth-CustomOAuthgranthandler
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Writing+a+Custom+OAuth+2.0+Grant+Type
But still when we enable the custom grant type and the start calling the token endpoint, the mentioned above errors are logged in the console.log and are returned as response by the tomcat server.
After we implemented some adjustments in order to resolve some of the issues, we have progress, but this still we do not have a complete solution:
https://slack-files.com/T0DDMMC9Y-F2S5LKT6V-560a2854ea

Could this be related to some issues while migrating from 5.0.0 to 5.2.0, or this is some sort of configuration issue with Tomcat server?
Or this is related to the grant type itself? We followed all the instructions as we did with IS 5.0.0 but we are not able to make it run on IS 5.2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause for this is,

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **org.apache.amber**.oauth2.common.validators.AbstractValidator

Amber library is no longer used by WSO2 IS. Therefore amber library is not available in the IS 5.2.0 runtime causing the class not found error. 
Instead, we are using Apache Oltu instead in 5.2.0

You can simply fix this by copying the amber amber_0.22.1358727.wso2v4.jar found in *IS_HOME/repository/components/plugins* of IS 5.0.0 to IS_HOME/repository/components/dropins.

---

Update :

Another reason why this extension was not working was the use of a class that was not exported by the OAuth osgi bundle at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the proposed by you approach with my older version of the custom grant. Indeed I was able overcome the issue with password grant. However when I tried to use the custom grant I received the following: https://slack-files.com/T0DDMMC9Y-F2RTN10A1-3b34f5eb8d . Then I came accross https://github.com/wso2/product-is/tree/master/modules/samples/oauth2/custom-grant and updated the validator to use org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.validators.AbstractValidator and when I tried to use the grant type I received https://slack-files.com/T0DDMMC9Y-F2RTW4PRQ-277765eb45

Comment: We did some modifications of the custom grant itself but still we are getting error when trying to use the custom grant:
https://slack-files.com/T0DDMMC9Y-F2S5LKT6V-560a2854ea

Comment: if there's no concern can you share the code of the custom grant type you have written? One issue I saw is the custom grant type is trying to access an internal class of OAuth bundle(org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth/internal/OAuthComponentServiceHolder) which is not exported by it. This cause a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: This is a link to the package - https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5j1e4ua6imn0yx/impersonate.7z?dl=0. Thank you for the help. I know there are changes between the versions but I am not able to find information that could help me upgrade the custom grant type. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you change line #120 to                 RealmService realmService = IdentityTenantUtil.getRealmService(); and try?

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. It worked once I changed this line and added "import org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityTenantUtil;". After that the custom grant type was loaded successfully and I was able to call it and retrieve the desired information.

Comment: great! the reason it didn't work was that you were using a class which is note exported by the oauth osgi bundle at runtime